# Cross Join in Hive

Tags: sql, datetime, join, hive, window-functions

I'm trying to create a new column `time_period` while running the query below. If the date difference between a given transaction and the most recent transaction in the reference table is fewer than 7 days, then mark it as a `recent` transaction, else mark it as an `old` transaction.

However, the query below is generating an error in the subquery associated with the cross join. The error is "Cannot recognize input near 'select' '(''max'

```
SELECT
    c.*
    FROM(
        SELECT
         a.acct_nb,
         a.txn_date,
         a.txn_amt,
         (CASE WHEN datediff(b.most_recent_txn,a.txn_date)<7 THEN 'recent' ELSE 'old' END) AS time_period
         FROM db.t1 a
         CROSS JOIN(
              SELECT max(txn_date) AS most_recent_txn --ERROR OCCURS HERE
              FROM db.t1 b)
        )c
        WHERE c.time_period='new';
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: You may be missing a comma after `a.txn_amt`

Comment: Thanks, just a typo in writing up a condensed version of the query for SO. Corrected the post.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to match your query - parentheses is in different position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias `b` should be applied to the cross joined subquery and not to the table `db.t1` inside the subquery:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (
  SELECT a.acct_nb, a.txn_date, a.txn_amt,
         CASE WHEN datediff(b.most_recent_txn, a.txn_date) < 7 THEN 'recent' ELSE 'old' END AS time_period
  FROM db.t1 a
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT max(txn_date) AS most_recent_txn
    FROM db.t1 
  ) b
) c
WHERE c.time_period='new';
```

Also, there is no branch of your `CASE` expression returning `'new'` so the last `WHERE` clause will filter out all rows.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `join` for this. You can just use window functions:

```
SELECT 
    acct_nb,
    txn_date, 
    txn_amt,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MAX(txn_date) OVER(), txn_date) < 7 
        THEN 'recent' 
        ELSE 'old' 
    END AS time_period
FROM db.t1
```

If you need to filter only on recent transactions, then you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT acct_nb, txn_date, txn_amt, MAX(txn_date) OVER() max_txn_date
    FROM db.t1
) t
WHERE DATEDIFF(MAX(txn_date) OVER(), txn_date) < 7
```

Comment: @Caerus . . . Window functions are almost always the better solution, if there is a solution using them.

Comment: @GMB thank you--very elegant solution. To ensure I understand, when you don't specify a field after the OVER() statement, does the window default to the entire table?

Comment: @Caerus: yes, exactly.